# Unable to modify date in PHP / add days

Tags: php, date, datetime, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have written the following code for the app I'm working on:

```
$tmp = $this->getConfig()['brandIds'];
$unexpired_brands = array();
$expired_brands = array();

foreach($tmp as $key => $value)
{
    $brand = $this->getBrandModel()->getBrandById($value);
    $currentDate = new \DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $startDate = new \DateTime($brand["startDate"]);
    $expireDate = date_add($startDate, date_interval_create_from_date_string('7 days'));
    // this date right here gets modified and on its original value 7 days are added

    if($currentDate>$expireDate)
    // Checking if current date is bigger than expire date.(Ex. 20.5.2016 > (startDate)+7 days) ? Yes
    // Assumption is that start date is < currentDate
    {
        date_add($brand["startDate"],date_interval_create_from_date_string("7 days"));
        // However?? This one isn't ?? It stays the same as the one that is fetched from
        // the db, which is $brand["startDate"] == currently set on 2016-05-10
        array_push($expired_brands,$brand);
    }
    else
    {
        date_add($brand["startDate"],date_interval_create_from_date_string("7 days"));
        // neither this one is modified ??? How can I modify these date as the one I've shown above??
        array_push($unexpired_brands,$brand);
    }
}
```

As you can see above, I'm unable to modify the date value that I've fetched from DB, and I'm able to modify the local variable that I've created to check if the `currentdate` is bigger than expiry date...

Can someone help me out with this? Thanks heaps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is `$brand["startDate"]` a date? Make a `var_dump($brand["startDate"])` statement; it should tell you the variable type.

Answer (score 0):

I see that

```
date_add($startDate, date_interval_create_from_date_string('7 days'));
```

worked but

```
date_add($brand["startDate"],date_interval_create_from_date_string("7 days"));
```

didn't work.

Maybe it's the double quotes that's the issue and you didn't add

```
new \DateTime($brand["startDate"])
```

Change the ones that didn't work with

```
date_add(new \DateTime($brand["startDate"]),date_interval_create_from_date_string('7 days'));
```

since it seems like you are trying to do the same thing.